# move row of divs down when overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic div boxes created in a website, I want to have 4 boxes in each row using bootstrap, that's working, but each box has some text at the bottom, the problem is that when the text is too long and it creates a new line, the div expands but the box underneath this div moves to the right, instead of moving all the row underneath down.
This is the html:

```
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat=""class="col-sm-3 album-art"> //loop to create the boxes
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="box">
            <span class="play" ng-click="">&#9658</span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <img src= height="200" width="200">
        <p>text</p>
        <p><i>text</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css I have:

```
.album-art{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.thumb {
    position: relative;
}
.thumb .box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Basically what I'd need is that when the text overflows and creates a new line, the row below the current row moves down and not move every element to the right.The problem seems to be in the "album-art" class, since I removed all the other classes and the problem still there.

thanks

EDIT: I've added images for a better explanation

This is when everything is normal
[image]

But when the text is longer
[image]

EDIT2: I put an example here: [jsfiddle.net/qgo7a701](http://jsfiddle.net/qgo7a701) you might have to expand the result area to the left in order to see 4 squares per row

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you question very well , but in bootstrap the row divided to 12 cell, and you can define divs in row with different sizes.and you can use col-[xl,lg,md,sm,xs]-[1 to 12] classes for that. you can look to this link :
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

for you example below i have tried to make two row with two boxes and i only break the text to prevent it to overflow to next div

```css
.album-art{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p{
       word-break: break-all;
}
.thumb {
    position: relative;
}
.thumb .box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat=""class="col-sm-3 album-art">
    
    //loop to create the boxes
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="box">
            <span class="play" ng-click="">&#9658</span>
            <div class="overlay">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src= height="200" width="200"/>
        <p style="">text helooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
        <p><i>text</i></p>
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    <div ng-repeat=""class="col-sm-3 album-art">
    
    //loop to create the boxes
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="box">
            <span class="play" ng-click="">&#9658</span>
            <div class="overlay">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src= height="200" width="200"/>
        <p style="">text heloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
        <p><i>text fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</i></p>
    </div>
    
</div>
   
</div>



<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat=""class="col-sm-3 album-art">
    
    //loop to create the boxes
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="box">
            <span class="play" ng-click="">&#9658</span>
            <div class="overlay">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src= height="200" width="200"/>
        <p style="">text helooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
        <p><i>text</i></p>
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    <div ng-repeat=""class="col-sm-3 album-art">
    
    //loop to create the boxes
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="box">
            <span class="play" ng-click="">&#9658</span>
            <div class="overlay">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src= height="200" width="200"/>
        <p style="">text helooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
        <p><i>text</i></p>
    </div>
    
</div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I think that's not the problem, I've edited the post with images for a better explanation.

Comment: can you provide full example with two row and four boxes as mention in jsfiddle or snippet

Comment: you can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/qgo7a701/ you might have to expand the result area to the left in order to see 4 squares per row.

Comment: I'm gonna take a look into this but I have to ask you first, have you tried with display: table applied to the container?

Gonna check it later!

Answer (score 0):

I tested what you did and it was working as intended. You used 1 row for the complete collection of cols, so they behaved as intended. To change that, you must force a grouping of cols and you can do it like this:

(Resume here:
 - Add **div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table"** and close it after 4 of your "*col-sm-3 divs*". Add another one for the rest of the "*col-sm-3 divs*". Everything should be inside the **div class="row"**. (I would have used two rows every 4 "col-sm-3 divs" but, is your code).
 - Change the "*style*" into a css, include it in your stylesheet, add the class to the div. End.

```css
.album-art {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.thumb {
  position: relative;
}
.thumb .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .album-art {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .thumb {
      position: relative;
    }
    .thumb .box {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table;">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">tedddddddxxxx ewhuiofhew hfiuhiufw shidfshksdhxfffffffffffffxxxxxddddddxt</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table;">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
        <div class="thumb">
          <div class="box">
            <span class="play"></span>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="#" height="50" width="50" />
          <p style="color: black">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```